# Android pie edittext typed text not showing when soft keyboard is open

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

Edittext input text is not visible and I type in using soft keyboard but once I press next you button I am able to see the input value. code is working fine on older android versions but not on android pie.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 27):

This seems to be an issue with Android Pie. I changed hardware acceleration to true in the manifest and it worked.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: Had the same issue where this solved it. However, in my case I was able to find one more alternative solution: constraint layout. This was causing the issue, so to speak. Removing (or upgrading it) would also resolve it. So, if for whatever reason you don't want to add that attribute, you may want to look up into refactoring your xml.

Comment: This worked for me too. But don't understand how it worked.

Comment: ui related issue

Comment: Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel