# Lower TextInputEditText not displaying text while typing, only displayed after done (or) next action (or) when tapping anywhere in screen

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Below is my code for EditText,

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/username_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:hintEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/login_username_input"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/password"
                android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_done"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/submit_btn"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I am setting password eye icon programatically like below,

```
passwordLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE);
                passwordLayout.setEndIconDrawable(GetDrawable.getDrawable("Show/Hide Password"));
                passwordLayout.setEndIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white)));
```

This works fine in most of the devices. But getting below issue in Mi a2 Android Version 10.

I have two TextInputLayout for user name and password field
There is no issue while typing username field.
Next moved to password field. Now, ***the cursor stucked in first position and typing text is showed up in keyboard but not displayed in Edittext field. Only text is displayed after tapping somewhere else in screen***

****I am not sure why this happens in some devices****

Found below question related to my issue. But no solution provided there.

[TextInputEditText is not showing the typed text/number when typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62827653/11630822)

***UPDATE***

In this given a solution for my issue, [Android Pie edittext does not adjustPan/resize while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196952/android-pie-edittext-does-not-adjustpan-resize-while-typing?noredirect=1&lq=1) but using Hardware acceleration may lead to high memory usage. So afraid to use this solution.
is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: `EditText.invalidate()`

Comment: @Darkman Hii.. can you explain your answer. Where I want to do this? and I am using TextInputEditText

Comment: First of all, no guarantees it would work. Try calling `invalidate()` to update the UI everytime a user enter a letter or word. If it doesn't work, you're better leave a comment so that others be informed and can help you.

Comment: @Darkman Okay will try

Comment: Try removing android:background="@drawable/round_bg" from your TextInputEditText and check if the problem still exists. When you do that try also to change your textColor if needed.

Comment: @MariosP In my case only the lower TextInputEditText has issue. Upper TextInputEditText works fine.

Comment: @Sandhiya Both TextInputEditTexts have the same background drawable (round_bg) and the upper one works fine?

Comment: @MariosP yes yes

Comment: @Sandhiya This issue occur in both cases when you write the password in visible mode (plain text) and when you write the password in hidden mode?

Comment: @MariosP No, only checked in hidden mode. Actually when moving from upper to lower TextInputEditText, cursor itself will be stuck or not displayed.

Comment: @Sandhiya Can you click on the password eye icon and check if the issue still exists also in visible mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228582/discussion-between-sandhiya-and-mariosp).

Comment: Found the exact solution in below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022269/android-pie-edittext-typed-text-not-showing-when-soft-keyboard-is-open

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on emulator on two android devices find nothing wrong with it used `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0`

- please update your color style it has no Legiblity

[image: her]

- pan Adjuesment related issued loged in debug check that
- try alpha or Rc MDC for libaray version bug
- Finally you do is open issue at MDC github [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

Comment: got this issue only in Mi a2 device. Working fine in most of the devices

Comment: MDC edit text actually inherited platform edit text (in this case your mi a2) if there are bug /incompatibility (most possible device end) you need to contact device manufacture or MDC github issue tracker. in most case need to find a bug where exits in device or lib itself Device Debug Log may help to identify problem you can post log